# Cannot delete fortigate gre tunnel

Tags: fortigate, fortinet

I have created a GRE tunnel on Fortigate 1100E. Now I want to remove this tunnel, but I receive this error:

```
Current vf=root:0.
A tunnel interface cannot be deleted directly.
Command_cli_delete:6677 delete table entry Test-Tun unset oper error ret=-160.
```

I've deleted all related static routes and policies. I've also activated the `ref` column and deleted all references (Now it shows 0 reference), but the problem still persists and I cannot delete the tunnel. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete from system->gre-tunnel

#config system gre-tunnel
#delete "gre interface"

After that the gre interface will be deleted